# use anchor tag in thumbnai image to redirect to category page in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have used a logo slider and called `the_post_thumbnai()` function to show image. The thumbnail comes from different category. Now when I keep anchor tag and use permalink, it links to me in `single.php` page.
I want to redirect the link to product page which has same category.
I used the following code,

```
<?php 
$categories=get_the_category();
$output='';
 if($categories){
foreach ($categories as $category ) {
$output.='<a  href="'.get_category_link($category->term_id).'?slug='.$category->slug.'">'
.$category->cat_name.'</a>';
 }
  echo $output;
 }?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
    $categories=get_the_category();
    $output='';
   if($categories){
      foreach ($categories as $category ) {
          $args = array(
                        'category'         => $category->term_id    ,
                        'post_type'        => 'post',
                        'post_status'      => 'publish',
         ); 
          $posts_array = get_posts( $args );
           foreach ( $posts_array as $post ) :  
              setup_postdata( $post );
              $output.='<a  href="'.get_permalink();.'">'
             .$category->cat_name.'</a>';
          endforeach; 
        wp_reset_postdata();
      }
      echo $output;
   }?>
```